# Transfer ethers from smart contract to an account in metamask

Tags: solidity, javascript, react

**I want to transfer 10 ether from smart contract to an account in metamask.
I used the following script inside my smart contract :**

```
 function transferBalance(address payable Add) public{
           
       Add.transfer(10 ether);
           
       }
```

It is not working and I got the following message on metamsak.

[image]

and I got the following error on the console:
[image]

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Does the contract _have_ 10 ether?

Comment: If not, send 10 eth to the contract and then try it.

Comment: contract has balance more than 10 ether but not sure why it is not working.